# Getting 400 bad request in Axios but in Postman status 200

Tags: axios, powerbi, postman, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to request a Power BI API using axios.

```
var configReportInfos = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${process.env.GROUP_ID}/reports/${process.env.DASHBOARD_ID}`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.accessToken
    },
    data: {}
};

let reportinfos
try {
    reportinfos = await axios(configReportInfos)
    tokenResponse['reportInfos'] = reportinfos
}

catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
};
```

Actually I'm getting this error

> Request failed with status code 400"

But strangely in Postman I'm getting 200 status.

[image]

I'm using same token.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When l switched content-type in my app to  application.json everything worked.

Comment: I just noticed that its a GET request. I might be wrong but I think you do not need to set header for GET request. Check: http://zetcode.com/javascript/axios/
it should be just:
axios.get('http://webcode.me').then(resp => {

    console.log(resp.data);
});

Or you can use async/await, you have example for that also on this page.

Comment: even by deleting `Content_Type`I get the same error

Comment: Try to use as I mentioned in previous comment. Try to use axios.get(url) instead of passing complete configuration in axios. And check is everything good with authorization setup. If that still does not work then I have no idea what else could cause the problem.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not know what else could cause that problem. If you manage to find solution please update this post, since I would like to know what was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue (not in Axios) and struggled for a few hours.
I was able to make the API call from postman but from my java code I was getting a 400.
Turns out, this was a content issue. My request body had some Cyrillic content and it needed to be encoded before sending.
Postman was doing it by default and hence the requests were going through and responding with 200

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check your **Request Header options** in most cases some option is configured wrong.

In your case **content-type** seems wrong, did you try application/json in both calls.

To configure properly you can check the documentation
[Content Type Configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)